# Interpreting cause of segfault with GDB nexti

Tags: c++, assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb, x86-64

So, I'm debugging a program which mysteriously crashes via a SIGSEGV.  The program is single-threaded.

I've debugged many segfaults before - most of them come down to stack or heap corruption.  It's usually easy to debug heap corruption problems with valgrind.  Stack corruption is trickier, but you can usually at least tell that stack corruption is the problem when GDB shows that your stack is mangled.

But, here I've encountered a very bizarre problem which I've never seen before.  Using GDB to go instruction by instruction, I see that the segfault happens immediately after a `callq` instruction.  Except the `callq` address is not dynamically loaded from a register or from memory - it's just a *static* function address:

```
(gdb) ni
0x00007ffff659c423      223         setPolicyDocumentLoader(docLoader);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff659c423 <WebCore::FrameLoader::init()+351>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
(gdb)
0x00007ffff659c426      223         setPolicyDocumentLoader(docLoader);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff659c426 <WebCore::FrameLoader::init()+354>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
(gdb)
0x00007ffff659c429      223         setPolicyDocumentLoader(docLoader);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff659c429 <WebCore::FrameLoader::init()+357>:
    callq  0x7ffff53a2d50 <_ZN7WebCore11FrameLoader23setPolicyDocumentLoaderEPNS_14DocumentLoaderE@plt>
(gdb) ni

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000683670 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x683670:    add    %al,(%rax)
(gdb)
```

So, as soon as it executes `callq` to the address `0x7ffff53a2d50`, it suddenly segfaults.

I realize that, in general, Stackoverflow can't possibly be too helpful for most segfaults or problems like this, because the reasons tend to be extremely specific to some particular circumstance, and usually just come down to memory corruption via programmer error.

But I still thought it would be worth asking this question because this fundamentally doesn't even make any sense to me.  How is it even *possible* for the OS to deliver a SIGSEGV when a program executes a `callq` instruction to a legitimate *statically* determined function address?

Comment: `ni` steps over the `call`. The fault is elsewhere, deeper. You should use `si` instead to step into the called function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nexti` will execute the next instruction, but if the instruction is a `call` then it executes until the function returns. From the [GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping):

> nexti, nexti arg, ni
>
> > Execute one machine instruction, but if it is a function call, proceed until the function returns. An argument is a repeat count, as in next.

When you do the `callq` the debugger called into that function but then crashes somewhere during execution of that function. If you want to step into a function call then I'd recommend `stepi` when you hit `callq  0x7ffff53a2d50`

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as it executes callq to the address 0x7ffff53a2d50, it suddenly segfaults.

This is usually caused by stack overflow.

Look for deep recursion (using `where` command). Also look at your stack region (containing current `$rsp` value) in output from `info proc map`.

Comment: But wouldn't stack overflow only trigger the segfault on a `push` instruction? A call instruction isn't actually increasing the stack size or moving up the stack pointer

Comment: It's definitely not a stack overflow via deep recursion (the call stack is only 7 frames), and it's not a stackoverflow via running out of stack space - a simple experiment of placing a variable in `main` and then calculating the stack size at the point of crash shows that the stack is less than 1000 bytes

Comment: @Siler A `CALL` instruction `PUSH`es return address on the stack, and *does* actually decrease stack pointer.